# Javascript Variable Declaration Issue

Tags: javascript

```
var Stars = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var StarsX = new Array(451,455,460,470,490,100,160,220,280,300);
var StarsY = new Array(451,455,460,470,490,480,390,330,200,120);
var Starsm = Stars
var StarsmX = StarsX
var StarsmY = StarsY

//just shows the output of the variables in a text field
function contpost(){Tfield.innerHTML=Stars + "<br/>" + StarsX + "<br/>" + StarsY + "<br/>" + Starsm + "<br/>" + StarsmX + "<br/>" + StarsmY;}

//cycles through the "for" loop and posts the variables
function newpost(){
for (var i=0;i<Stars.length;i++){
    StarsmX[i] = StarsX[i] + 10;
    StarsmY[i] = StarsY[i] + 10;
    }
contpost()
}


var Tfield= (This is the text field)
var canv_one= (This is a canvas in my document)
canv_one.addEventListener('click', newpost);
```

If I run this code (Firefox 9), the if/then loop adds 10 to both the "mX" variable and the "X" variable.

I now know approximately how it does it. It's simply because I set them equal early on. When I substitute this in the declarations, it works properly:

```
var Starsm = new Array()
var StarsmX = new Array()
var StarsmY = new Array()
```

What I don't understand is why javascript is doing this. It seems logical to me that if you set them equal once, during the global declaration, they will not re-equate later on (and do it backward, at that. I never set StarsX equal to StarsmX.)

I'm pretty sure this means I'm not understanding some kind of basic functionality of Javascript, and that worries me.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Just an aside: when creating an array the preferred syntax is `[]` rather than `new Array()` (shorter, easier to read, and avoids the problem where calling `new Array(5)` creates an array with five elements rather than a single element with value 5). So `var Stars = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];` and `var Starsm = [];`

Comment: OK. I'll go back and change that later. I'm basically learning Javascript from whatever I can google. ...Best practices aren't always clear.

Comment: Cool. You may like to look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide. Also, a Google tip: if you want to find out about some JavaScript keyword or function, add " mdn" or " mdc" to the end of your Google search terms, e.g., "array mdn" - this will tend to bring the MDN page about that keyword/function to the top of the search results - you generally don't even need the word "javascript".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't adding anything to the variable. It's adding to the Array, and both variables reference the same Array object.

This is because in JavaScript you only get to hold a *reference* to an object, not the object itself. So the reference to the Array is the value being copied, not the Array.

If you wanted a shallow clone of the Array, use `slice()`.

```
var Starsm = Stars.slice()
var StarsmX = StarsX.slice()
var StarsmY = StarsY.slice()
```

Or just do as you said, and create empty Arrays.

Comment: So you're saying that basically, what I did is say that "starsm" is now a variable that contains the array "stars"?

My intention was to create a new array with the name "Starsm" (etc) that cloned the original.

Comment: @user1120353: Yes. `var Starsm = Stars` copies the object reference held by `Stars`, so they both end up with a reference to the same Array object. To (shallow) clone the original Array object, you can use `.slice()`.

Comment: Thanks. The idea that I could do that hadn't even occurred to me for some reason.

I appreciate the prompt help.